# Routing Between Cisco 4507R+E Layer 3 Switch & UTM Firewall Fortigate

Tags: routing, switch, firewall, layer3

Please Help me.

I have a Cisco Catalyst 4507R+E and UTM Firewall Fortigate and I Created VLANS on Catalyst and the main VLAN port Which Play IP Route between All VLANs can not connectet to the UTM Firewall unless create No Switch Port.

What is the Difference between Switch port mode & No Switch Port .

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

As said above switchport set the port to be layer 2, you assign a vlan to it and then need an SVI to configure L3 for ip connnectivity. If you do no switchport the port is layer 3 and you place an IP address directly on the port. I am guessing you want a static default route between the switch and the firewall. Dont forget you need routes in the firewall pointing back to the subnets you have configured in the switch

Answer (score 3):

`switchport` means the interface is in layer 2 mode, forwarding frames as a switch. `no switchport` means the interface is in layer 3 mode, routing packets.